# Attempting to append number chars in a filename to a new file

Tags: java, file

I am attempting in Java to grab a file name, select the first eight characters from this file name and then append them to a new file name, I'm not entirely sure how to go about this and I'm not entirely sure my approach is even the correct way to go about this but here is my attempt so far: (Above this I have code to copy a new file from one directory to another this works)

```
for (String file : files) {
    File srcFile = new File(src, file);
    String fileName = null; 
    new File(fileName).getName();    
    String fileNames;    
    fileNames = "Split after 8 characters!";    
    if (fileNames.length() > 16)
        fileNames = fileNames.substring(0, 8) + "...";  
    File destFile = new File(dest, file);    
    copyFolder(srcFile,destFile); 
    fileName.renameTo(fileNames);    
}
```

The only thing giving me an error at the moment is the `.renameTo` at the bottom and the error given is

> cannot find symbol   symbol:   method renameTo(String)   location:
>   variable fileName of type String Dereferencing null pointer

Comment: What do you think happens in the two lines: `String fileName = null; new File(fileName).getName();`?

Comment: I think this sets the filename var to null, gets the name of whatever is in fileName, oh sugar I've just realised that it can't grab the name as it's set to null, I cannot remove null or I get a hint to set it to null though :s - Now I'm really confused

Comment: I have this variable is because I wanted it to store the current file name in the variable so I could work with it, but now I've noticed this isn't the case and I'm not sure what to do to get around this

Comment: What type kind of String do you have in your `file` what you tale out of the `files` collection. Shouldn't the name of the file be in there allready, at least partially? parsing your filename out of the `String file` should be the straight forward attempt.
Also what happens here `fileNames = fileNames.substring(0, 8) + "...";`? Do you actually append three dots (which are not viable in a file name) or is it just a place holder, where in your code something else is written?

Comment: Looking at `if (fileNames.length() > 16)`: Since `fileNames` is the string `Split after 8 characters!` and that is 25 characters, code will run `fileNames = fileNames.substring(0, 8) + "..."`, so you end up with a value of `Split af...`. Now, what was the point of that exercise?

Comment: I was attempting to manipulate another persons example on here as I have no real clue as to how to attempt this, it appears pointless, also it's a string array @Akunosh

Comment: From what you told us so far, you are trying way more than you actually need. just pick your filename from your array, like you already do. If you are sure that file name allways is long enough, just get the first eight letters with the `.substring()` like you already do. And then append whatever string you you want next and possibly also add te file extrension you want to that string. With that string you can then either greate a new file or rename an existing file depending of what your original purpose is.